# TypeError: styled_components__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.vedio is not a function on react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Here I'm trying to play a vedio on my webpage which is located on vedios folder.

I installed *npm i styled-components*

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import Vedio from "../../vedios/home_vedio.mp4";
import { HeroContainer, HeroBg, VedioBg } from './HeroElements';

const HeroSection = () => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg> 
                <VedioBg autoPlay loop muted src={Vedio} type = 'vedio/mp4' />
            </HeroBg>    
        </HeroContainer>
    )
}

export default HeroSection
```

**HeroElements.js**:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
.....
.....
export const VedioBg = styled.vedio `
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #232a34;
`
```

**Here is the error**:

TypeError: styled_components__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.vedio is not a function

[image: error image]

Is there any problem with my importing part..!?

I'm beginner on react any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong tag in the line:

```js
export const VedioBg = styled.vedio `
```

Regardless of what you use in the future `react` or `react-native`, they do not have a tag with that name. Most likely this is just a typo and it is correct to use the `video` tag

Try this:

```
const HeroSection = () => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg> 
                <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type = 'video/mp4' />
            </HeroBg>    
        </HeroContainer>
    )
}

export default HeroSection
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
.....
.....
export const VideoBg = styled.video `
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #232a34;
`
```

P.S. I fixed `vedio` on `video` everywhere except the file name.

Comment: Exactly this. For a full list of supported DOM elements, OP can view [this file](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/src/utils/domElements.js)

Comment: Thank for the help @xom9ikk

Comment: thanks for refering the full list of styled-components @mattCarlotta